# ping ip's / hostname in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to ping an ip address and telnet to some port from an app hosted on app engine. I've tried using http://svn.pylucid.net/pylucid/CodeSnippets/ping.py but for some reason it failing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE does not support ICMP nor Telnet.

For communication with outside hosts at the moment only mail/xmpp/http(s) work through the specific API calls.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that ICMP messages can only be
>   sent from processes running as root.

Your app on GAE is not running as root. Why bother pinging when you want to telnet anyway?