# npm Ping on Node.js app. ICPM not send when app deployed to Google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ping, icmp

I have ticket tracking app on Node.js
I deployed it on Google App Engine and it is available on : 
https://ticket-master-230204.appspot.com/

All functionalty works if I just run it in cloud console. Or in Amazon Cloud 9 without deploying. However after I deployed it on App Engine, one of the function stooped working properly. And I can't figure out why.

So if You open any of the tickets :
https://ticket-master-230204.appspot.com/tickets/5c3c5201afce691354161e08

You would see that Ping functionality is not working. 
For some reasons my app can't receive echo response .
Once again if not deployed everything works perfectly fine.

So when You click on a ticket it should take you to show page for that particular ticket.
What happens in the back end at this time it takes array of hosts (basically any hostnames or ip addresses) and making ping tests for all of them. Then It returns a result and basing on that result host names are red or green.

What I'm using:
1) Node js
2) Express
3) Ping
4) Passport
5) MOngo
So bellow is route for show page.
I think it should something to do with incopming traffic permissions but I allowed everything in settings.
[App engine Firewall settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxfVb.png)

```js
//4. "SHOW" ROUTE.
          app.get("/tickets/:id", async function (req, res) {
          let foundTicket = await Shift.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec()
          let hosts = ( JSON.stringify(foundTicket.fqdn) )
          console.log(hosts)
          let host1 = hosts.substring(2,hosts.length-2).split(',')
          console.log(host1)
          let msg=[];
           await Promise.all(
            host1.map((host) => (
             ping.promise.probe(host)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        msg.push(res);
                         console.log(msg);
                    })              
            ))
          )  ;
```

I have no idea where else I can allow incoming traffic to my app.
Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to use ICMP on app engine, not that I have tried. The only reference that I can find for this is [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488430/ping-ips-hostname-in-app-engine), which is a very old answer. There is some docs for other languages but not for node.js on outbound request protocols [Link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/outbound-requests#request_protocols). Hope this helps.

Comment: Do You know any other way to implement ping test of the host ? I just do not want to deploy it on VPS hosting since this app is for my portfolio purpose only. Thanks in advance. And thanks for previous reply.

Comment: no other way since it's app engine itself that's doing the blocking.